# Why does my dropdown menu not work when using Include?

Tags: php, include, navbar

So I have a navigation bar (code below) that works when it is hard coded into my webpages but when I separate it and try to use "include" the dropdown menu attached to my login button does not work anymore. All files are in php and I am using bootstrap primarily. Wondering if anyone knows a reason for this not working and a possible solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hands On Lab</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/7.0.0/jquery.mark.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>
        mark {
        background: orange;
        color: black;
        }
    </style>
 <body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hands On Lab</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="./ongoing.php">Ongoing Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./closed.php">Closed Projects</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="/action_page.php">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" id="searchfor" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav dropdown">
                        <a class= "nav-link drowpdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                <input class="form-control login" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email.."><br>
                                <input class="form-control login" type="password" name="pswd" placeholder="Password.."><br>
                                <input class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:black" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
                                <br>
                                <a href="./registration.php">Sign up Here</a>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
 </body>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
        $("input").on("input.highlight", function() {
            // Determine specified search term
            var searchTerm = $(this).val();
            // Highlight search term inside a specific context
            $("#context").unmark().mark(searchTerm);
        }).trigger("input.highlight").focus();
        });
     })
    </script>
 </html>
```

Comment: Define "does not work". Doesn't load at all? Doesn't drop down? Looks wrong? Also, seems like you have posted the working (hardcoded) version of your code?

Comment: Yeah new to this but this was the code that was being pulled into another page via "include" but I figured it out. Needed to remove the header section.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging PHP by placing `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of the file where the error occurs.

Most likely in your case there will be an error like `No such file or directory in .../dropdown.php on line 110` because PHP cannot find the file you are trying to include.

Comment: Figured it out i simply needed to remove the header section. When i used include on another page it was pulling this header and placing it in the body causing issues.